# Azure PowerShell: Get-AzVM does not display the output

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

According to this [Official document example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-5.1.0#example-4--get-all-virtual-machines-in-your-subscription) from MS Azure team, the following command should display all the `VMs` in my current subscription. But when I logged-in with my subscription and run the following command, it just brings me back to the command line with no output and no error. I do have `VMs` in this subscription, and the same login with the same subscription is working for other tasks I am performing in the same session. **Question**: What I may be missing here, and how can we resolve the issue?

```
PS C:\Users\MyUserName> Get-azVM
PS C:\Users\MyUserName>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you Signed into [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-5.1.0) Connect-AzAccount

Do you have more than one subscription?
If so you might need to switch subscriptions.

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

Comment: Yes. Welcome to StackOverflow. I am using then new [az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.1.0) and not the old one `AzureRM` module

Comment: It worked now after using Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx". Include your comment in your response. I'll mark it as an Answer so to complete this post - thank you.