# Get-AzVM returns empty list on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform

I have some terraform code that creates a set of VMs in Azure in a single resource group, that works fine and is quite reliable as expected. However, after creating the resources, I do fetch the VMs using Get-AzVM to run some additional configuration.

Since a few days ago Get-AzVM has been misbehaving and returns an empty list for several minutes, even though you can see the resource group and the VMs in Azure Portal.

I'll share the Get-AzVM command down below, but there is nothing out of extraordinary:

```
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup | Where-Object Name -Like $Pattern
```

I have even added a retry loop, but it seems to be stuck for several minutes.

Note that the subscription is properly set and using other `$ResourceGroup` works instantly.

Did anyone ever see something like this?

Comment: Does `Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup` return anything by itself (ie. without `... |Where-Object Name -Like $Pattern`)

Comment: Not for this case no, and I can confirm from Azure Portal that the `$Pattern` should work.

Comment: If it doesn't return anything when you remove `Where-Object`, that means it isn't related to the pattern at all - sounds more like you either got the wrong Resource Group name or the RG doesn't contain any VMs

Comment: Agree, but I am checking that same RG under Azure Portal and it is there with the expected VMs. It looks like a stall, because after a few minutes it starts responding properly. Of course there is not much I can do besides adding a very long retry loop or something like that.

Comment: I guess another possibility, would be to rely on terraform to collect the VM names with output variables (since the amount is dynamic)

Comment: Please look at this [Azure PowerShell: Get-AzVM does not display the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971465/azure-powershell-get-azvm-does-not-display-the-output)

Answer (score 0):

assign the o/p to a variable and then display the result.. see if that works.

$vmlist = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup | Where-Object Name -Like $Pattern

$vmlist

Comment: Leomoty, Did you find the Answer?